# The file name when I downloaded it was object object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is body request [image]
Here is my code

```
fetch(`${proxy()}${dataUrlExport}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Accept:
          exportType === "excel"
            ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            : "text/csv",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(exportBody),
    })
      .then((res) => res.blob())

      .then((blob) => {
        if (exportType === "csv") {
          const bom = new Uint8Array([0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf]);
          const withBom = new Blob([bom, blob], { type: "text/csv" });
          blob = withBom;
        }
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        ////////console.log(1300, url)
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.style.display = "none";
        a.href = url;

        const datetimeString = getCurrentDateTimeForFilename();

        const segments = page.page_title.split("/");
        const lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1]; //tên
        const result = lastSegment.replace(/-/g, "");
       
        a.download =
          exportType === "excel"
            ? `DATA_${result.toUpperCase()}_${exportBody.criteria}_${datetimeString}.xlsx`
            : `DATA_${result.toUpperCase()}_${datetimeString}.csv`;

        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        setLoadingExportFile(false);
        setSelectedFields([]);
        setSelectAll(false);
```

I want it to be included when I download the file name is exportBody.criteria: RF20243220001 but I get object

How do I get it and assign it to the filename?

tks guys

Comment: looking at the result of the request, `.criteria` IS an object (with a property `7MLSX`) - therefore `${exportBody.criteria}` WILL be `[object Object]` - perhaps you wanted `${exportBody.criteria["7MLSX"]}` - or even `${Object.values(exportBody.criteria)[0]}` if that `7MLSX` is some dynamic value

Comment: yupp as you said, I tried solving it this way and it works. const criteriaContent = Object.values(exportBody.criteria)

Comment: `const criteriaContent = Object.values(exportBody.criteria)` is close ... you forgot the `[0]`

Comment: Is it really necessary? while it only has the property is 7MLSX

Comment: did you read my comment? I suggested `${exportBody.criteria["7MLSX"]}` first ... and the one using `Object.values` **IF** the `7MLSX` is not a fixed key name (not the value, the key name) - but ... I see it may not be necessary if there's only one property in `exportBody.criteria`